# Cannot append numpy values into the list inside a loop

Tags: python, numpy

For the list p I cannot append numpy values. Error message and Code is given below.

[image]

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: This code is really awkward. There are pointless operations like the `asscalar` calls, or building lists where you don't need them. You recompute `np.argmax(output, axis=2)` over and over, too. NumPy code should almost never involve list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally reused p as an iterator in the line:

```
value = [p for p in X.T[index]]
```

so p was reassigned as a numpy.int32 instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You reused the `p` variable:

```
p = []
...
    value = [p for p in X.T[index]]
#                  ^
```

Pick a different name.